# React.js - the value in JSON is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I do :

```
console.log(storeAvailableHours[0]);
```

Below is the output:

```
currentDate: (3) [2021, 2, 24]
dayOfWeek: "WEDNESDAY"
deliveryMaxReadyMinutes: 60
deliveryMinReadyMinutes: 45
deliverySelectableTimes: (89) ["2021-02-24 01:50:00",...]
pickupMaxReadyMinutes: 25
pickupMinReadyMinutes: 15
pickupSelectableTimes: (91) ["2021-02-24 01:20:00"...]
today: true
```

But when i try

```
console.log(storeAvailableHours[0].dayOfWeek);
```

It shows 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'dayOfWeek' of undefined'. Why? The value is right there!!
Can someone please help me out?

I tried "storeAvailableHours&&storeAvailableHours[0].dayOfWeek" it doesn't work

Comment: send complete code from where you get storeAvailableHours data

Comment: Try: storeAvailableHours?.[0]?.dayOfWeek

Comment: storeAvailableHours?.[0]?.dayOfWeek  works!!!! Could you please explain how the question marks work?

Comment: The optional chaining ?. is a safe way to access nested object properties, even if an intermediate property doesn’t exist.